# Ruby model callbacks fail to run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, callback

Is there a situation where callbacks would fail to run?

Since about 4-5 day ago, callbacks have "appeared" to randomly stop running on some models. The problem is it is intermittent.

The simplest is:

```
after_create :generate_tokens
def generate_tokens
  self.update(ref: Devise.friendly_token[0,10])
end
```

There are models being created where ref is `nil`. Peppered seemingly randomly throughout the table.

When I redeploy which performs a reset on passenger, it starts working again. Clearly something in the code "breaks" and needs to be reset, but no errors or system complaints are displayed.

- Rails 4.2.0
- Ruby 2.2.1p85
- Apache/2.4.7
- Passenger 5.0.4

Thanks

Comment: Which version of rails you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I would change the `after_create` callback to a `before_validate` callback. Then `ref` is written into the database in the same transaction than the new object. And - as a bonus - you can add a validate the presence of a `ref` value to your model:

```
before_validation :generate_tokens, on: [:create]
validates! :ref, presence: true, on: :create

private
def generate_tokens
  self.ref = Devise.friendly_token[0,10]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord#update returns a boolean telling if the update has been done or not. Since the return is not used or catch your code might failed to pass (for validation error for instances) without your seeing an error.

Since the callback here is an after_create your object will be persisted but the generate_tokens might fall. I suggest you switch your code to

```
def generate_tokens
  self.update!(ref: Devise.friendly_token[0,10])
end
```

It will raise an exception, and therefore help you spot the issue.